# Will I be stopped by the immigration team when I travel from Paris to India if I don't have a valid Titre de Sejour. It's in process and it's pending

Tags: france

I applied for my first 'Titre de Sejour'. The process in the second stage now and I had received an ADP that states 'ce document n'autorise pas le franchissement des frontières de l'espace schengen'.

I am sure that I won't be allowed inside France if I don't get a récipissé but my question here is, WILL I BE STOPPED in the airport while I travel from Paris to India as I am still a Indian resident and I have a valid Indian Passport.

Comment: Are you planning on going back to France?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the main risk is being stopped. You haven't committed any crime and nobody should be prevented from leaving or going back to their country unless there are being investigated for a crime or something similar. Consider this: Even if you had been present in the country illegally (not your case), you shouldn't be prevented from leaving. And before you apply, you obviously don't have any document like the one you currently hold. It wouldn't make sense for an application to reside in France to curtail your freedom to leave so severely compared to someone who hasn't applied.

Instead the main risk is putting your French residence title into jeopardy, i.e. that you will be deemed to have abandoned your application. If that happens, you will not be able to fly back to France and you would have to restart the whole process from scratch should you ever want to live in France. And I mean not only the *titre de séjour* but the long-stay visa as well. Formally it's kind of separate but I can't see that history helping with short-stay visa either.

So in summary: If you just want to leave France for good and you are not interested in securing a proper residence permit, nobody should prevent you from returning to India. But if you want to come back soon, you should avoid leaving at this point in the process.